# Is Puerto Rico considered As USA for green card holder?

Tags: visas, usa, puerto-rico

Im a green card holder.
I wanted to know if Puerto Rico is considered as USA state for us.
Green card holder can’t be out of USA country for more than 6 months.
If I stay in Puerto Rico is it considered as being in the USA?